# JSON Array parsing where key is missing in the key-value pair

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a JSON Array which looks something like this

`"data":["data1","data2","data3"]`

If I write `JSONArray arr = obj1.getJSONArray("data");`, this will provide me with the JSON array but since the key name from key-value pair is missing, how will I retrieve "data1", "data2" and "data3"?

Comment: your json array should be like this {"data":["key1":"data1","key2":"data2","key3":"data3"]}

Comment: @RupeshRathod I cannot change my JSON. This json is fetched from an API and the API cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

JSON arrays allows for non json children. In this case, the children are of String value:

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++) {
    String value = arr.getString(i);
}
```

*My syntax might be inaccurate*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your JSON,

{"data":["data1","data2","data3"]}

Use the following to retrieve the array,

```
JSONArray arrJson = jsonData.getJSONArray("data");     
String[] arr = new String[arrJson.length()];     
for(int i = 0; i < arrJson.length(); i++) {    
    arr[i] = arrJson.getString(i);     
}
```